# How do I apply a procedural generated scratch overlay across multiple mesh

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

[image]

### What is going on

1. 100% procedural texturing is part of the goal
2. Each board is an individual mesh
3. Exact same material is used on each mesh
4. Material's nodes add a random value to Object Texture Coordinates to the z coordinates to generate the variations in the wood grain

### Goal

1. Procedural scratch across multiple mesh
2. Image texture is not an option

Comment: Use the *Vector Transform* node to transform object coordinates into *Scene World* coordinates

Comment: Using **Geometry Node**'s **Position** socket you are able to mark surfaces from a **global coordinates** perspective.  Simply add an overly once you have a desired pattern generating.  Here is an EXAGGERATED example just to show what happens.  Keeping in mind all the boards have exactly the identical material applied. Eliminating the need to apply image textures.

Comment: Do not include answers in the question. Add an answer to your own question please.

Comment: @Leander, I wish I could but I was blocked from answering because when I was totally noob 3 of my answers were down voted.  I was trying to save time for everyone by posting the answer, and leaving it here for whomever else needs this in the future. If you would like to copy & paste the answer, I will be glad to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **Geometry Node**'s **Position** socket you are able to mark surfaces from a **global coordinates** perspective.  Simply add an overly once you have a desired pattern generating.  Here is an EXAGERATED example just to show what happens.  Kepping in mind all the boards have exactly the identical material applied. Eliminating the need to apply image textures.

Of course the final scratching will be much more refined and detailed. :)

[image]